# duckduckstack - The StackExchange API Doc Autocompleter

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

> **NOTE (2nd April, 2012):** After an e-mail correspondence with DuckDuckGo's Gabriel W. I decided to take down this project (and remove it from GitHub) due to Terms of Service issues with aggregating search results. The short story: DDG aren't allowed to syndicate search results from external providers in other ways.
>
> I will try to implement the "autocompleter" functionality some other way in the future, so I'll keep this page for now. But until then hang tight. ;-)
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience.

## [DuckDuckStack](https://github.com/spoike/duckduckstack) - The Stack Exchange API Doc Autocompleter

[image: The thumbnail screenshot]

DuckDuckStack is a user-script that extends the Stack Exchange with an API docs *autocompleter*, powered by [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com/). It is a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) user-script and should run on Firefox and Chrome.

In Chrome you will need to also install the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) extension as the script uses features that native user-scripts can't (more specifically `@require` and `GM_xmlhttpRequest`).

### Usage

To use the autocompleter do the following:

1. Start writing an answer on a Stack Exchange answer. To start using the autocompleter you type in `api:` which will open a list of available search tags should appear that will filter as you continue typing. You can move the selection with up/down arrow keys and select with the enter key. The search tags will group in related and unrelated tags.
2. When you've selected the search tag it will auto-insert it into the text like this: `api:[search tag]:`. After this you can write a search term which will let the user-script do a relevant site search in DuckDuckGo and list them.
3. When you've selected the search result you want it will auto-insert the link into your post.

The screenshots below shows this three step flow:

[image: API Doc Completion Flow]

The token that the script reacts on looks like this: `api:[search tag]:[search term]`.

#### Supported Search Tags

The following tags are currently supported in the user-script:

- `css`, `html`, and `javascript` - Searches in [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org)
- `man` for man-pages - Searches in [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/)
- `msdn` - Searches in [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com)
- `jquery` - Searches in [JQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com)

I'll add more if there are any requests for such.

### Download

**Download link removed for now. See note above.**

### Feedback and bug reports

Feel free to drop some comments below and bugs are great if you enter them into the [bug tracker at GitHub](https://github.com/spoike/duckduckstack/issues).

### License and Credits

The user-script is licensed under the MIT License.

It requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQuery Caret Plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/plugins4jquery/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin/usage) which is loaded by the user-script. The logo is DuckDuckGo's.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug:

[image]

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a bug in the code. Reproducable in firefox, I'll try to look into it when I can during the weekend and see if I can debug and find the issue.

Comment: This should now be fixed in v0.2 and should work in the latest firefox